# pam_mount stopped working

Tags: 14.04, mount, automount, cifs, pam

This is how it worked: my Ubuntu workstations authenticate against Active Directory, and pam_mount mounts some CIFS directories on user logon. Now, for some reason, pam_mount stopped working and no directories are mounted. So, I enabled pam_mount debugging and see the following:

```
(rdconf1.c:744): path to luserconf set to
/home/DOMAIN/username/Documents/.pam_mount.conf.xml
(pam_mount.c:365): pam_mount 2.14: entering auth stage
(rdconf1.c:744): path to luserconf set to
/home/DOMAIN/username/Documents/.pam_mount.conf.xml
(pam_mount.c:568): pam_mount 2.14: entering session stage
(pam_mount.c:629): no volumes to mount
command: 'pmvarrun' '-u' 'username' '-o' '1'
(pmvarrun.c:258): parsed count value 0
(pam_mount.c:441): pmvarrun says login count is 1
(pam_mount.c:660): done opening session (ret=0)
```

So, no volumes to mount? My `pam_mount.conf.xml` looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE pam_mount SYSTEM "pam_mount.conf.xml.dtd">
<pam_mount>

<debug enable="1" />
<luserconf name="Documents/.pam_mount.conf.xml" />
<volume user="*" sgrp="residents" fstype="cifs" server="dfs.namespace.com" path="data/users/%(USER)/documents" mountpoint="~/Documents" options="uid=%(USER),gid=100,dir_mode=0700" />
<volume user="*" sgrp="residents" fstype="cifs" server="dfs.namespace.com" path="data/public" mountpoint="~/mount/Public" options="uid=%(USER),gid=100,dir_mode=0700" />

<mntoptions allow="nosuid,nodev,loop,encryption,fsck,nonempty,allow_root,allow_other,uid,gid,dir_mode" />
<mntoptions require="nosuid,nodev,uid,gid,dir_mode" />
<logout wait="0" hup="0" term="0" kill="0" />
<mkmountpoint enable="1" remove="true" />

</pam_mount>
```

and this configuration has worked for months, until now. I don't recall making any configuration changes lately. I suspect that an upgrade ruined it because one day I noticed this had happened on all of my workstations. And I have no idea where to look next :( Google hasn't been really helpful.

In `/var/log/syslog` it says:

```
Apr 23 11:25:54 hostname nslcd[1261]: [86d4c7] <authz="username"> ldap_result() failed: Operations error: 000004DC: LdapErr: DSID-0C0906E8, comment: In order to perform this operation a successful bind must be completed on the connection., data 0, v1db1
```

but honestly I've been seeing these errors in syslog since always, and as the LDAP authentication has worked fine (and still does) I haven't paid much attention to it. Logging on seems to work fine in `/var/log/auth.log`:

```
Apr 23 11:43:48 hostname su[10409]: pam_winbind(su:auth): getting password (0x00000388)
Apr 23 11:43:48 hostname su[10409]: pam_winbind(su:auth): pam_get_item returned a password
Apr 23 11:43:49 hostname su[10409]: pam_winbind(su:auth): user 'username' granted access
```

Other than that, I don't see anything relevant in `/var/log/syslog` or `/var/log/auth.log`. I have Ubuntu 14.04. I'm quite new to Linux and I'd appreciate if someone had some ideas what I'd try next :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this same issue after some updates today. I've done some testing and found that removing the sgrp="..." parameter to the volume allows them to mount. It looks like it thinks there are no volumes to mount because the user wasn't in the listed group.

This leads me to believe the problem is a result of this bug filed for the latest update to winbind that affects groups: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/samba/+bug/1573526

I've temporarily removed sgrp from my volumes and they seem to be mounting now. Hopefully that bug will get resolved and it will properly fix this. Hope this helps.

**UPDATE**: The bug linked above has been fixed and an update released, however I still had the same problem. Winbind was not returning group members for a given group (ie. "getent group " returned no members). Adding "winbind expand groups = 1" to smb.conf resolved this. I don't know if this relates to the new winbind update or not, but my groups are working again in pam_mount.conf.xml.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @chtaylor, I was originally able to resolve this by removing the `sgrp` attribute from all entries in `pam_mount.conf.xml`. Later I realized that **the `sgrp` attribute works only if the group is user's primary group**. So changing `sgrp="residents"` to `sgrp="domain users"` made the volumes available for me again because `domain users` is by default the primary group of all AD users. Another solution would be to change the primary group of desired users in Active Directory to match the pam_mount config:

Active Directory Users and Computers > go to user properties > Member Of > Set Primary Group